# Converting a data base output to xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Sorry guys I have updated the Issue below.

Though looked to be really simple earlier, later turned into a really complex thing.
Can anyone help me out?

I need this XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<RecordSet>
    <Data image="h1.gif" description="a"/>
    <Data image="" description="asdf" />
    <Data image="" description="bsdf"/>
    <Data image="" description="csdf"/>
    <Data image="h2.gif" description="b"/>
    <Data image="" description="dsdf"/>
    <Data image="" description="esdf"/>
    <Data image="h3.gif" description="c"/>
    <Data image="" description="sdff"/>
</RecordSet>
```

converting to this

```
 <RecordSet>
    <MenuHeader image="h1.gif">
        <Menu description="a"/>
        <Menu description="b"/>
        <Menu description="c"/>
    </MenuHeader>
    <MenuHeader image="h2.gif">
        <Menu description="d"/>
        <Menu description="e"/>
    </MenuHeader>
    <MenuHeader image="h3.gif">
        <Menu description="f"/>
    </MenuHeader>
</RecordSet>
```

Stylesheet used

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="RecordSet">
 <RecordSet>
  <xsl:for-each select="Data[not(@image='')]">
   <MenuHeader image="{@image}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="key('d',@image)"/>
   </MenuHeader>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </RecordSet>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="d"
     match="Data[@description]" 
     use="preceding-sibling::Data[@image][1]/@image"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Actual output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RecordSet>
    <MenuHeader image="h1.gif">
        <Data image="" description="asdf"/>
    </MenuHeader>
    <MenuHeader image="h2.gif">
        <Data image="" description="dsdf"/>
    </MenuHeader>
    <MenuHeader image="h3.gif">
        <Data image="" description="sdff"/>
    </MenuHeader>
</RecordSet>
```

Updated:
The Data node that does have the image attribute with value should be set as MenuHeader. Any help will be of really great help.

Comment: Do you really want `Menu` elements in the first and third `MenuHeader` and `Data` in the second one or is that a typo?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0, or just XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easier in XSLT 2, but using XSLT 1 for old time's sake:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="RecordSet">
 <RecordSet>
  <xsl:for-each select="Data[string(@image)]">
   <MenuHeader image="{@image}">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('d',@image)">
     <Menu>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@description"/>
     </Menu>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </MenuHeader>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </RecordSet>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="d"
     match="Data[not(string(@image))][@description]" 
     use="preceding-sibling::Data[string(@image)][1]/@image"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Produces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RecordSet>
   <MenuHeader image="h1.gif">
      <Menu description="asdf"/>
      <Menu description="bsdf"/>
      <Menu description="csdf"/>
   </MenuHeader>
   <MenuHeader image="h2.gif">
      <Menu description="dsdf"/>
      <Menu description="esdf"/>
   </MenuHeader>
   <MenuHeader image="h3.gif">
      <Menu description="sdff"/>
   </MenuHeader>
</RecordSet>
```

Note for the updated version of the question where you want have `image=""` rather than no image attribute, the test is `string(@image)` rather than simply `@image`.

Comment: I have updated the original issue using the method provided. Please help me resolve the problem...

Comment: @user2969793 Re your latest edit, this should just be a small change to the key definition to add a `!= ''` to the `use` clause: `preceding-sibling::Data[@image != ''][1]/@image`

Comment: Thanks Ian, I did try this previously and the problem was that for some reason it brought the last node, that is the supposed next menuheader along with previous set. I have made it work with yet another if condition. I will post it when I go to my work place.

Comment: I don't believe this produces the wanted output. It generates many more elements than the OP's desired solution.

Comment: @ABach it produced the exact requested solution before the OP edited the question to change the problem:-) I'll update it to fit the new question...

Answer (score 1):

2.0 option, push style.

**XML Input**

```
<RecordSet>
    <Data image="h1.gif"/>
    <Data description="a"/>
    <Data description="b"/>
    <Data description="c"/>
    <Data image="h2.gif"/>
    <Data description="d"/>
    <Data description="e"/>
    <Data image="h3.gif"/>
    <Data description="f"/>
</RecordSet>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Data" group-starting-with="Data[@image]">
                <MenuHeader image="{@image}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[not(@image)]"/>
                </MenuHeader>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <Menu>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </Menu>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<RecordSet>
   <MenuHeader image="h1.gif">
      <Menu description="a"/>
      <Menu description="b"/>
      <Menu description="c"/>
   </MenuHeader>
   <MenuHeader image="h2.gif">
      <Menu description="d"/>
      <Menu description="e"/>
   </MenuHeader>
   <MenuHeader image="h3.gif">
      <Menu description="f"/>
   </MenuHeader>
</RecordSet>
```

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I have been asked to use xslt 1.0 to maintain consistency. But really appreciate your help. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach using tail-recursion to approximate a "while" loop

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/RecordSet">
    <RecordSet>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Data[@image != '']"/>
    </RecordSet>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data[@image != '']">
    <MenuHeader image="{@image}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Data[1][@image='']" />
    </MenuHeader>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <Menu description="{@description}"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Data[1][@image='']" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The trick here is that the template generating the `MenuHeader` applies templates to just the first (if any) non-image `Data` element that follows it. That template then recursively consumes the next one etc. until we reach a point where the next one has an `image`, when the recursion will automatically stop.

Comment: Will try this and let you know Ian. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

<s>The accepted answer does not produce the output you say you want in your original post. This slightly modified version (still XSLT 1.0) should do the trick.</s>

Here is a different XSLT 1.0 alternative.

**When this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key
     name="kDataByPrecedingImage"
     match="Data[@image = '']"
     use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[@image != ''][1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="RecordSet">
    <RecordSet>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[@image != '']"/>
    </RecordSet>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data">
    <MenuHeader image="{@image}">
      <xsl:apply-templates
        select="key('kDataByPrecedingImage', generate-id())"
        mode="children"/>
    </MenuHeader>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Data" mode="children">
    <Menu description="{@description}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the given XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RecordSet>
  <Data image="h1.gif" description="a"/>
  <Data image="" description="asdf"/>
  <Data image="" description="bsdf"/>
  <Data image="" description="csdf"/>
  <Data image="h2.gif" description="b"/>
  <Data image="" description="dsdf"/>
  <Data image="" description="esdf"/>
  <Data image="h3.gif" description="c"/>
  <Data image="" description="sdff"/>
</RecordSet>
```

**...the desired result is produced:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RecordSet>
  <MenuHeader image="h1.gif">
    <Menu description="asdf"/>
    <Menu description="bsdf"/>
    <Menu description="csdf"/>
  </MenuHeader>
  <MenuHeader image="h2.gif">
    <Menu description="dsdf"/>
    <Menu description="esdf"/>
  </MenuHeader>
  <MenuHeader image="h3.gif">
    <Menu description="sdff"/>
  </MenuHeader>
</RecordSet>
```